# How do I control which applications receive mouse input?

Tags: mouse

On Windows I have been using [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) to control which applications receive mouse input. I need to know how to do this on a Mac.

Specifically I am using Mumble and want to bind the "back" button on the mouse to Push To Talk globally. It must have no action in any other application.

I'm using an [MMO 7](http://www.cyborggaming.com/prod/mmo.htm) mouse. But sadly the software that comes with it does not have this functionality.

Comment: What mouse are you using? Does it have custom driver software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [USBOverdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) in the past with Logitech gaming mice. ( Not for gaming but the number of buttons)

The app gave me control over what buttons would trigger when in different apps. It has global options also.

> The USB Overdrive is a device driver for Mac OS X that handles any USB mouse / trackball / joystick / gamepad / media keyboard and any Bluetooth mouse from any manufacturer and lets you configure them either globally or on a per-application, per-device basis. Note that the Apple Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad are not handled by the USB Overdrive to let Mac OS X implement its full multitouch support.
>
> The USB Overdrive reads all kinds of wheels, buttons, switches and
>   controls and assigns them to useful actions like clicking, typing,
>   scrolling, launching, opening documents and so forth. It can easily
>   handle several USB devices at once and can assign different settings
>   to each one.
>
> The USB Overdrive works in Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), 10.7 (Lion)
>   and 10.8 (Mountain Lion) in both 32-bit and 64-bit modes. Users of
>   previous Mac OS X releases should stick with version 3.0.1 of the USB
>   Overdrive.

Comment: This is an acceptable solution. Sadly I can't have the Cyborg drivers enabled, but I'd rather have this. Thanks.